# SharePoint and Cmis connection is not able to check in docx,pptx,xlsx type docs

Tags: 2013, cmis

I have an application that connects to SharePoint 2013 through Cmis Apache chemistry. I am to upload a doc, check out a doc through my application using Cmis but when I try to check in docs of type docx,pptx,xlsx its custom properties do not retain.

SharePoint is not able to check-in docs back and application crashes with exception as 'customaccessdenied'. But it is not in the case of doc,ppt and xls.

Please help if you know anything.

Comment: Could you please split into two questions? One for the custom properties not retained, and one for the customaccessdenied. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please say what Chemistry library you are using: OpenCMIS? PortCMIS? DotCMIS? Another?

Comment: Hi..I am using OpenCmis and the issue is custom properties not retained on the new version of the document.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now, please create a separate question for the customaccessdenied problem.